# T-SQL round to decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I round the result of matchpercent to two decimal places (%)?
I'm using the following to return some results:

```
DECLARE @topRank int
set @topRank=(SELECT MAX(RANK) FROM
FREETEXTTABLE(titles, notes, 'recipe cuisine', 1))
SELECT 
    ftt.RANK, 
    (CAST(ftt.RANK as DECIMAL)/@topRank) as matchpercent, --Round this
    titles.title_id, 
    titles.title
FROM Titles
INNER JOIN 
FREETEXTTABLE(titles, notes, 'recipe cuisine') as ftt
ON
ftt.[KEY]=titles.title_id
ORDER BY ftt.RANK DESC
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

CAST/CONVERT the result:

```
CAST((CAST(ftt.RANK as DECIMAL)/@topRank) AS DECIMAL(n,2)) as matchpercent,
```

...where `n` is a number large enough not to truncate left of the decimal point.  That is to say, if you use "123.456", you need to use DECIMAL(7,2) because the total length is 7 digits.