# Rounding off to two decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, rounding

I need to convert minutes to hours, rounded off to two decimal places. I also need to display only up to two numbers after the decimal point. So if I have minutes as 650, then hours should be 10.83.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Select round(Minutes/60.0,2) from ....
```

But in this case, if my minutes is, say, 630 - hours is 10.5000000. But I want it as 10.50 only (after rounding). How do I achieve this?

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: If T-SQL, this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190688/t-sql-round-to-decimal-places

Answer (score 471, accepted):

You could cast your result as `numeric(x,2)`. Where `x <= 38`.

```
select
    round(630/60.0,2),
    cast(round(630/60.0,2) as numeric(36,2))
```

Returns

```
10.500000    10.50
```

Comment: Strange. `SELECT ROUND(630/60.0, 2);` gives me `10.50` already.

Comment: @u07ch what is the purpose of using round() when you are already using a cast?

Comment: @Ram The question didn't specify the sql server engine - which is why i highlighted the round v cast on its own. The convert to numeric doesn't do rounding in all engines so if the calculated number was 10.809 you would get 10.80 rather than the 10.81 the question required.

Comment: `cast(630/60.0 as numeric(36,2))` is enougth `10,50`

Comment: in ms sql `cast (150.755555 as numeric (16,2));`  gives `150.76`

Comment: casting to Numeric will round and to Integer will truncate. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#truncating-and-rounding-results

Answer (score 103):

With [SQL Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2012), you can use the built-in [*format* function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx):

```
SELECT FORMAT(Minutes/60.0, 'N2')
```

Comment: Note that this introduces thousands separators as well, e.g. `1,757.47`

Comment: Using '0.00' rather than 'N2' gives two decimal places without also have the thousands separator.

Comment: Seems to convert to string ?  which screws up order by.

Comment: @blissweb Should not be a problem as you can order on the original column, not the output of the Format function.

Answer (score 40):

You can use:

```
select cast((630/60.0) as decimal(16,2))
```

in SQL Server

Comment: At least on DB2, this does not round the result.

Comment: That is a bold statement. What was it tested on?

Comment: decimal(16,2) doesn't limit decimal places to 2.

Comment: @julianjoseph it does in SQL-Server.

Answer (score 17):

```
Declare @number float = 35.44987665;
Select round(@number,2)
```

Comment: Consider adding a bit of an explanation to your answer.

Comment: In case of decimal (10,6) what will happen?

Comment: In MS SQL Server this will produce the exact problem in question. The output will be 35.44000000

Answer (score 15):

```
CAST(QuantityLevel AS NUMERIC(18,2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for the code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its [long-term value](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by describing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: nice this one should one of the best answe so far.. why I said that...

Answer (score 6):

Convert your number to a `Numeric` or `Decimal`.

Replace your query with the following.

**[SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server)**

```
Select Convert(Numeric(38, 2), Minutes/60.0) from ....
```

**[MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL):**

```
Select Convert(Minutes/60.0, Decimal(65, 2)) from ....
```

The `Cast` function is a wrapper for the `Convert` function. Couple that with SQL being an interpreted language and the result is that even though the two functions produce the same results, there is slightly more going on behind the scenes in the `Cast` function.

Using the `Convert` function is a small saving, but small savings multiply. The [parameters for Numeric and Decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (38, 2) and (65, 2) represent the maximum precision level and decimal places to use.

Comment: Thank you for being the only person to provide SQL Server and MySQL solutions, AND provide an explanation

Answer (score 4):

Following query is useful and simple-

```
declare @floatExchRate float;
set @floatExchRate=(select convert(decimal(10, 2), 0.2548712))
select  @floatExchRate
```

Gives output as 0.25.

Comment: What was it tested on?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, On MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @porcentaje FLOAT

SET @porcentaje = (CONVERT(DECIMAL,ABS(8700)) * 100) / CONVERT(DECIMAL,ABS(37020))

SELECT @porcentaje
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```sql
    SELECT CAST(ROUND([Amount 1]/60,2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) as TOTAL
```

Answer (score 3):

This works in both with [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) and Oracle:

```
SELECT ename, sal, round(((sal * .15 + comm) /12),2)
FROM emp where job = 'SALESMAN'
```

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you use in denomination should be in decimal. For example, `1548/100` will give `15.00`.

If we replace `100` with `100.0` in our example then we will get `15.48`

```
select 1548/100
15.00000

select 1548/100.0
15.4800

0
```

Comment: Re *"in denomination"*: Do you mean *"in the [denominator](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denominator#Noun)"*?

Answer (score 2):

As an add-on to the answers below, when using INT or non-decimal datatypes in your formulas, remember to multiply the value by 1 and the number of decimals you prefer.

I.e. - `TotalPackages` is an `INT`, and so is the denominator  `TotalContainers`, but I want my result to have up to six decimal places.

Thus:

```
((m.TotalPackages * 1.000000) / m.TotalContainers) AS Packages,
```

Answer (score 2):

*This worked for me:*

```
SELECT FORMAT(Minutes/60.0, '0.00')
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet might help you:

```
select SUBSTR(ENDDTTM,1, 9), extract(DAY FROM (ENDDTTM)), ENDDTTM, BEGINDTTM,  (ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM),substr(BEGINDTTM, 1,15), substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 12, 8),
round((substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 12, 2)* 3600 + substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 15, 2)*60 +  substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 18, 2)),2) as seconds,
round((substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 12, 2)* 60 + substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 15, 2) +  substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 18, 2)/60 ), 2)as minutes,
round((substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 12, 2) + substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 15, 2)/60 +  substr((ENDDTTM - BEGINDTTM), 18, 2)/3600 ),2)  as hours
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the STR function the cleanest means of accomplishing this.

```
SELECT STR(ceiling(123.415432875), 6, 2)
```

Comment: Won't ceiling round this up to 124?

Answer (score 0):

To *round up* to x decimal places:

```
SET @Result = CEILING(@Value * POWER(10, @Decimals)) / POWER(10, @Decimals)
```

where *@Value* is the value of the item to be rounded, *@Decimals* is the number of decimal places, for example, two in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT CAST((630/60.0) AS numeric(16,2)) FROM ...
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was as follows in the Redshift environment, citing from the top 2 answers:

```
cast(round(630/60.0,2) as numeric(36,2))
```