# SQL rounding to a 2 decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, rounding

This should be an easy one but it is driving me around the bend

I have a very simple query like

```
select a, b, c
from DataTable
```

which produces always 6 decimals, but I want to change the number of decimals being displayed and also the number of decimals being displayed by each field. At the moment I'm getting the following:

```
a        b        c
1.000000 2.123456 3.123456
```

and I want the following:

```
a  b    c
1  2.12 3.123
```

The fields a,b,c are defined in the table as decimal (18,4) and I'm using SQL Server 2008.

I tried to use `round(b,2)` but keeps always the 6 decimals.

I tried `floor(a)`, but it changes all results (a,b,c) to no decimals.

Any ideas on this strange behaviour?

Comment: See this pls - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: cast(round(a/1.0,2) as numeric(36,2))

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the duplication