# How to round 2 select columns results? SQL

Tags: sql, decimal, multiple-columns, rounding

How do I approach rounding this statement? count_shares has a datatype of decimal and post_ID has the datatype of int... The classic ROUND() is not applicable... Thanks for your response, I really really really appreciate it

```
(SELECT SUM(count_shares))/(SELECT COUNT (post_ID)) AS [RATIO];
```

Comment: Why is round not applicable?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am finding the ratio of shares/postID. For example in this case the answer is 0.200000, however I want the answer in 2dp...

Comment: When I use round in this statement (SELECT  (SELECT SUM(count_shares))/(SELECT COUNT (post_ID)) ROUND ,2) AS [RATIO] it gives me an error of Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about MS SQL, you need to use may need to use cast.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND((a.first_sum/b.second_value),2) AS numeric(38,2))  as [ratio] FROM
(SELECT SUM(1+2+3+4+5+100.2) as first_sum) a,
(SELECT SUM(6+7+8+9+10) as second_value) b;
```

Another answer [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places) covers this a little bit.