# Calculate group percentage to 1 decimal places - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL at the moment:

```
SELECT Count(create_weekday), 
   create_weekday, 
   Count(create_weekday) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                                  FROM   call_view 
                                  WHERE 
   ( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                    INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND ( create_year = Year( 
         Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND customer_company_name = "Company"
       ) AS Percentage
 FROM   call_view 
WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND customer_company_name = "Company" 
   GROUP BY CREATE_WEEKDAY
ORDER BY (CASE CREATE_WEEKDAY
WHEN 'Monday'   THEN 1
WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN 2
WHEN 'Wednesday'   THEN 3
WHEN 'Thursday'   THEN 4
WHEN 'Friday'    THEN 5
WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN 6
WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7
ELSE 100 END)
```

It's working and I received the result:

```
Count(create_weekday) | Create_Weekday | Percentage
225                       Monday          28.0899
```

How do I round to only 1 decimal place?( Like 28.1)

Would appreciate any help

Comment: `cast(Percentage as decimal(4,1))`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rounding off to two decimal places in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/rounding-off-to-two-decimal-places-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROUND(Percentage, 1):

```
SELECT Count(create_weekday), 
   create_weekday, 
   ROUND(Count(create_weekday) * 100 / (SELECT Count(*) 
                                  FROM   call_view 
                                  WHERE 
   ( create_month = Month(Now() - 
                    INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND ( create_year = Year( 
         Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND customer_company_name = "Company"
       ), 1) AS Percentage
 FROM   call_view 
WHERE  ( create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND ( create_year = Year(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) ) 
   AND customer_company_name = "Company" 
   GROUP BY CREATE_WEEKDAY
ORDER BY (CASE CREATE_WEEKDAY
WHEN 'Monday'   THEN 1
WHEN 'Tuesday'   THEN 2
WHEN 'Wednesday'   THEN 3
WHEN 'Thursday'   THEN 4
WHEN 'Friday'    THEN 5
WHEN 'Saturday'  THEN 6
WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7
ELSE 100 END)
```

Comment: Thanks, Working =)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the built-in `ROUND(N,D)` function, the second argument is the number of digits.

MySQL Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Answer (score 0):

As Jarlh stated, `cast(Percentage as decimal(4,1))` sets this to a decimal value with 4 places and 1 fraction place. The column value of `Percentage` will be rounded into this criteria.

Comment: Note that the rounding behavior of casting is different to "normal" rounding. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-rounding.html

Comment: @Lucero I can't find anything on the MySQL site or your link relating to `DECIMAL` or `CAST` in regards to their rounding method being different from `ROUND` .

Comment: I'm assuming that the current percentage number is a floating-point number, e.g. "approximate" in MySQL terminology. Also I expect implicit and explicit cast to behave the same, which would mean that the cast always does "round half away from zero" and not "round to nearest even" as `ROUND` would. Haven't explicitly tested this case though.

Comment: @Lucero ahhh, I didn't read any specifics on this, nor on a declaration that CAST and ROUND specifically worked differently. But useful to know anyhow. Feel free to update the anwser.

Comment: I think it's good enough that it is in the comments along with the mysql documentation link explaining this difference. In the end it should boil down to the required/expected target type; if one wants a decimal use the cast, if one wants to keep the same data type (probably float here) use round. The question is not clear on that point.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.  I would not recommend `round()`, because this doesn't really change the underlying representation.

You can convert the value to a string, using `format()`, or just convert the value to a decimal/numeric.  This looks like:

```
SELECT . . .
       CAST(Count(create_weekday) * 100 /
            (SELECT Count(*) 
             FROM call_view 
             WHERE (create_month = Month(Now() - INTERVAL 1 month) )  AND
                   (create_year = Year( Now() - INTRVAL 1 month) ) AND
                   customer_company_name = 'Company'
            ) as DECIMAL(4, 1)
           ) as Percentage
```