# SQL get decimal with only 2 places with no round

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query (`SQL Server`) that returns a decimal. I only need 2 decimals without rounding:

[image]

In the example above I would need to get: **3381.57**

Any clue?

Comment: `cast(numcol as decimal(12,2))`?

Comment: @jarlh, OP wants truncation, no rounding...

Comment: @Shnugo, does MS SQL Server's `cast` round? Unexpected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Rounding off to 2 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could accomplish this via the [`ROUND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx?) function using the length and precision parameters to truncate your value instead of actually rounding it :

```
SELECT ROUND(3381.5786, 2, 1)
```

The second parameter of `2` indicates that the value will be rounded to two decimal places and the third precision parameter will indicate if actual rounding or truncation is performed (non-zero values will truncate instead of round).

**Example**

[image]

You can [see an interactive example of this in action here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/7758).

Comment: You might add a `CAST(ROUND(...) AS DECIMAL(12,2))` ... +1 from my side

Comment: If assigning this value elsewhere, make sure your field/variable or whatever is `DECIMAL(19,2)` (the `2` is the key to only show two decimal places, the `19` refers to before the decimal point). Otherwise you'll get something like `3381.5700` displayed. Took me a little while to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the representation, you need to output the value as a string.  One method is to convert to a decimal and then to a string:

```
select cast(cast(total as decimal(10, 2)) as varchar(255))
```

Another method is to convert to a string using `str()`.  However, this often requires the removal of spaces:

```
select replace(str(total, 10, 2), ' ', '')
```

Comment: Both suggestions will round this to 3381.58... and btw: there's one paranthesis to much (first suggestion after total)...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `TRUNCATE`:

```
SELECT 3381.5786, {fn TRUNCATE(3381.5786,2)};
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/NPL4164)**</kbd>

Comment: Funny, haven't seen this before [ODBC scalar functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630290.aspx)