# How to round a number to 2nd decimal from a SQL query returned to textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I have 3 textboxes that receives a int value from 3 SQL queries that already uses the `ROUND()` function. But the result in the textbox returns 4 decimal points.. ie I require the value `xxxxx.xx` but the SQL query instead returns `xxxx.xxxx`.

Here is my code

```
private void totalRef_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=10.0.0.3,1434;Initial Catalog=client_orders_test;**Logins omitted**");

    SumTotalquery = "Select ROUND(SUM(value),2) from costings_cur";
    SumExVatquery = "Select ROUND(SUM(value-(value*14/100)),2) from costings_cur";
    SumVatquery = "Select ROUND(SUM(value*14/100),2) from costings_cur";

    SqlCommand totalQry = new SqlCommand(SumTotalquery, conn);
    SqlCommand exVatQry = new SqlCommand(SumExVatquery, conn);
    SqlCommand vatQry = new SqlCommand(SumVatquery, conn);

    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader DR1 = totalQry.ExecuteReader();

    if (DR1.Read())
    {
        total_txtbox.Text = DR1.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }

    conn.Close();

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader DR2 = exVatQry.ExecuteReader();

    if (DR2.Read())
    {
        exvat_txtbox.Text = DR2.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }

    conn.Close();

    conn.Open();

    SqlDataReader DR3 = vatQry.ExecuteReader();

    if (DR3.Read())
    {
        vat_txtbox.Text = DR3.GetValue(0).ToString();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

I have even tried using this:

```
exvat_txtbox.Text = DR2.GetValue(0).ToString().Trim();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `DR1.GetValue(0).ToString("#.##");`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places -- but why are you initiating 3 connections -- you could do this all in one connection/query and just return 3 columns.

Comment: You should be able to use a format specifier like so `DR1.GetValue(0).ToString("F")`. For detailed explanation and other options see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @BryanWoodford thanks but placeholders in this situation did not work. tried using ToString("0.00"); as well with no luck..

Comment: @JiggsJedi that question relates to a sql query within sql and not when the DB is queried remotely. If i use my initial query within SSMS i get the desired result. but not from my application. the issue is with C# returning the results to the textbox.

Comment: as with @JaydipJ answer i first needed to cast int as decimal to return decimal with ToString() to textbox. then placeholders aren't necessary

Comment: as with my 3 connections i will refine and combine into one query and one connection opened. I first needed to test my idea.. Thanks for everyone who helped with an answer

Comment: Side notes: **first**, don't close and reopen the connection over and over again - just **leave it open** while the three queries execute! **Second** - since you're retrieving just a single value (single column, single row), it would be much better to use `.ExecuteScalar()` instead of having a reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `Decimal(18,2)` to get correct result

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(SUM(value),2) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) FROM costings_cur
```

Similar way for others SELECT Statments.

> Note : [Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms175003.aspx) function just make rounding of number for specified length, it is not responsible for to get data in specific format.

Comment: thanks for the help..Your answer worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

1. use a numeric format string eg `ToString("0.##")`
2. use the search to avoid duplicated questions... ;)