# Calculation is always rounded

Tags: sql, mysqli, rounding

```
SELECT goals, games, ROUND(goals/games, 2) AS "goalspergame"
FROM bgoals
ORDER BY goals DESC, games ;
```

This always gives 1,00 and 0,00 as a result instead of the exact number rounded on two decimal places. If I put 100* in front of goals, then I get a useful result as percent, however I don't want to have it in percent.

What can I do in order to get a useful result?

I already used the search function, but nothing worked so far. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380227/7335773) seems to be good, but I either don't get how to use it right or it doesn't work.

Comment: try `ROUND(CAST(goals AS FLOAT)/games, 2) ` -- not sure if it would work with mysql though

Comment: Thanks, but if I try to do it like that I get an error that says that ROUND command does not exist. A different user provided an easy solution that works though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're getting integer division, I'm assuming `goals` and `games` are integers. A simple fix is to multiply by 1.0 to get a decimal result:

```
SELECT goals, games, ROUND(goals*1.0/games, 2) AS "goalspergame"
FROM bgoals
ORDER BY g.goalsscored DESC, g.ggamesplayed ;
```

Integer types, when divided, return integer results, but if either the numerator or denominator is a decimal, it will return a decimal result.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Didn't know I have to do this for integers

Comment: @hacker1337ninja  If the answer worked for you,  it would be polite to accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
'SELECT goals, games, ROUND(CAST(goals AS FLOAT)/CAST(games AS FLOAT), 2) AS "goalspergame"
FROM bgoals
ORDER BY g.goalsscored DESC, g.ggamesplayed'
```