# SQL : Round off to 1 decimal Point

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, rounding

I am trying to round my value to one decimal, below is sample which I tried.

```
INPUT     DESIRED OUTPUT
129.700   129.7
129.769   129.8
```

I have tried

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(('129.768'),0) AS DECIMAL(10,1))
FROM Table1
```

is not giving correct value.

Please help.

Comment: Havr you checked here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: You just need to change the second argument of round function from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want one digit after the decimal place, so that would be an argument of `1`, not `0`:

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND('129.768', 1) AS DECIMAL(10, 1))
```

I'm not sure why you feel the need to convert back to a decimal -- unless you are saving the value to a table and want to control the type.  This also does what you want:

```
SELECT ROUND('129.768', 1)
```