# SQL two decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to make `persen_sukses` or `persen_gagal` only get 2 decimal ?

[image]

I try use round but get some error.
May be anyone can help me.

Here is my sql

```
    SELECT * ,(CASE WHEN all_trx.trx_gagal = 0 THEN 100 WHEN all_trx.trx_sukses = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(all_trx.trx_sukses AS float)/CAST(all_trx.trx_total AS float)*100) END) AS persen_sukses,
(CASE WHEN all_trx.trx_sukses = 0 THEN 100 WHEN all_trx.trx_gagal = 0 THEN 0 ELSE (CAST(all_trx.trx_gagal AS float)/CAST(all_trx.trx_total AS float)*100) END) AS persen_gagal  
FROM 
(SELECT kode_produk AS Produk, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_sukses, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN status > '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_gagal, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN status >= '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_total 
FROM transaksi WHERE CAST(tgl_entri AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  GROUP BY kode_produk) 
AS all_trx
```

Comment: `cast(ColumnName as decimal(9,2)`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for full details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - Rounding off to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/sql-rounding-off-to-2-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
,(CASE  
        WHEN all_trx.trx_gagal = 0 THEN 100 
        WHEN all_trx.trx_sukses = 0 THEN 0 
        --ELSE (CAST(all_trx.trx_sukses AS float)/CAST(all_trx.trx_total AS float)*100) 
        ELSE CAST(all_trx.trx_sukses*100.0 / all_trx.trx_total as numeric(18,2) )
 END) AS persen_sukses
,(CASE 
        WHEN all_trx.trx_sukses = 0 THEN 100 
        WHEN all_trx.trx_gagal = 0 THEN 0 
        --ELSE (CAST(all_trx.trx_gagal AS float)/CAST(all_trx.trx_total AS float)*100) 
        ELSE CAST(all_trx.trx_gagal*100.0 / all_trx.trx_total as numeric(18,2) )
    END) AS persen_gagal  
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    kode_produk AS Produk, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_sukses, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status > '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_gagal, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status >= '20' THEN 1 END) AS trx_total 
FROM transaksi 
WHERE CAST(tgl_entri AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  
GROUP BY kode_produk
)  AS all_trx
```

Dear i am able to fix the issue in your query, Pleae note the only change i did is ELSE part of Case Statement. I executed the query and now returning the value upto two decimal places only. If you have to increase or decrease the digits after the decimal sign update the value of numeric(18,2) here 2 is number of digit after  decimal.