# SQL - Rounding a math expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, rounding

I am trying to get a value rounded to two decimal places. However the results in the following code is still displaying 4 decimal places

```
select p.ProductName, p.UnitPrice, s.CompanyName, c.CategoryName,
 case 
    when c.CategoryName in ('Condiments', 'Beverages') then round((UnitPrice + (UnitPrice * .2)), 2)
    when c.CategoryName in ('meat/poultry', 'seafood') then round((UnitPrice + (UnitPrice * .15)), 2)
    when s.CompanyName = 'New Orleans Cajun Delights' then round((UnitPrice + (UnitPrice * .08)), 2)
    else p.unitprice
 end as NewUnitPrice
from products p
join Categories c on c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
```

[image]

Comment: Simplify (you shouldn't need 3 tables to show us your rounding problem) - [mcve].

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh using MSQL

Comment: `else p.unitprice` is probably the culprit. Change it to `else ROUND(p.unitprice,2)`.

Comment: @kmoser negative. This did not fix

Comment: MSQL? Do you mean MS SQL Server?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: @JamesKrueger Your example shows NewUnitPrice as six decimal places, not four. Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: The new unit price should be 2 decimal places 21.60 instead of 21.600000

Comment: How can it matter how many trailing zeros there are? The number is still the same, the zeros is just a display function which you handle in your front end.

Comment: @kmoser no it does not solve.

Comment: And also, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380197/rounding-off-to-two-decimal-places-in-sql) is another similar question.

Comment: @DaleK because I only want 2 decimals. It should not be difficult to achieve.

Comment: @JamesKrueger Which specific solution(s) did you try and what was the output?

Comment: @JamesKrueger - you need to edit your question and explain **how** that duplicate question doesn't resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change the data type to 2 points of precision. See the example below.

```
SELECT
    CAST(2.49532785 AS NUMERIC(32,8)) AS [Original]    --Original 8 precision numeric
    ,ROUND(CAST(2.49532785 AS NUMERIC(32,8)),2)  AS [Rounded]    --Rounded 8 precision numeric
    ,CAST(2.49532785 AS NUMERIC(32,2))  AS [Cast]    --Original 2 precision numeric
```

Comment: It would be better to mark this question as a duplicate instead of answering it.  There are so many questions like this on SO.  We don't need to answer yet another one....