# Does rounding work if you call it on an operation in parentheses in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, numbers, rounding

Basically I can't get the rounding method to work. I want to round the price to 2 decimal places; I have tried to follow examples out there but it's just ignoring it. So I must be missing something.

This is what I have so far

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    CONVERT(varchar, pord.dt_created, 1) AS [Date Created], 
    pord_line.supplier AS [Supplier],  
    pord_line.ref_no AS [Purchase Order],
    pord_line.qty_received AS [Quantity Received], 
    pord_line.qty- pord_line.qty_received AS [Quantity Oustanding],
    pord.currency AS [Currency], 
    -- pord_line.price* pord_line.qty_received AS [Amount Received in Euros],
    -- pord_line.price * (pord_line.qty-pord_line.qty_received) AS [Amount Outstanding In euros]
    ROUND((pord_line.price * pord_line.qty_received), 2 )AS [Amount Received in Euros],
    ROUND(((pord_line.price * (pord_line.qty-pord_line.qty_received))), 2) AS [Amount Outstanding In euros]
FROM 
    pord_line (nolock)  
JOIN 
    pord ON pord_line.ref_no = pord.ref_no
WHERE 
    pord.dt_created BETWEEN '2015-10-08' AND '2015-11-08' ;
```

It is the following code which isn't performing as I intended

```
ROUND((pord_line.price * pord_line.qty_received), 2 )AS [Amount Received in Euros],
ROUND(((pord_line.price * (pord_line.qty-pord_line.qty_received))), 2) AS [Amount Outstanding In euros]
```

[image: Image of results I get]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Round to decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190688/t-sql-round-to-decimal-places)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function does not change the datatype; if input the expression is `DECIMAL(18, 10)` the result is also `DECIMAL(18, 10)`:

```
SELECT ROUND(1.0153456789, 2) -- 1.0200000000
```

If you want exactly 2 digits then cast the result to `DECIMAL(n, 2)`:

```
SELECT CAST(1.0153456789 AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) -- 1.02
```

And your query would become:

```
CAST(pord_line.price *                  pord_line.qty_received  AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Amount Received in Euros],
CAST(pord_line.price * (pord_line.qty - pord_line.qty_received) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) AS [Amount Outstanding In euros],
```

Answer (score 0):

(Please don't use images to display data on stack overflow for code or data)

As for your question: round does not *format*. what you can do is either use [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or try [cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) :

```
 Cast(ROUND( (pord_line.price * pord_line.qty_received), 2 ) as Decimal(10,2))  AS [Amount Received in Euros],
```

Answer (score 0):

Rounding works but you receiving result as for example decimal(15,10) - 10 precision. try casting your result to decimal (18,2)

```
CAST( ROUND( (pord_line.price * pord_line.qty_received), 2 ) as decimal(18,2)) AS [Amount Received in Euros]
CAST( ROUND( ((pord_line.price * (pord_line.qty-pord_line.qty_received))), 2) as decimal(18,2)  AS [Amount Outstanding In euros]
```